# Sorting lines according to the numerical value of the first element on each line?

Tags: perl, sorting

I have just started learning Perl, hence my question might seem very silly. I apologize in advance.

I have a list say `@data` which contains a list of lines read from the input. The lines contain numbers that are separated by (unknown number of) spaces.

Now, I would like to sort them and print them out, but not in the lexicographical order but according to the numerical value of the first number appearing on the line.

I know this must be something very simple but I cannot figure out how to do it?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), capturing the first number in the row with a regex

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @sorted =    map $_->[0],
                sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
                map { [ $_, /^(-?[\d.]+)/ ] } <DATA>;
print @sorted;

__DATA__
21  13  14
0   1   2
32  0   4
11  2   3
1   3   3
```

**Output:**

```
0       1       2
1       3       3
11      2       3
21      13      14
32      0       4
```

Reading the transform from behind, the `<DATA>` is the file handle we use, it will return a list of the lines in the file. The first `map` statement returns an array reference `[ ... ]`, that contains the original line, plus the first number that is captured in the line. Alternatively, you can use the regex `/^(\S+)/` here, to just capture whatever non-whitespace that comes first. The sort uses this captured number inside the array ref when comparing lines. And finally, the last `map` converts the array ref back to the original value, stored in `$_->[0]`.

Be aware that this relies on the lines having a number at the start of the line. If that can be missing, or blank, this will have some unforeseen consequences.

---

Note that only using a simple numerical sort will also "work", because Perl will convert one of your lines to the correct number, assuming each line begins with a number followed by space. You will have some warnings about that, such as `Argument "21    13      14\n" isn't numeric in sort`. For example, if I replace my code above with

```
my @foo = sort { $a <=> $b } <DATA>;
```

I will get the output:

```
Argument "21    13      14\n" isn't numeric in sort at foo.pl line 6, <DATA> line 5.
Argument "0     1       2\n" isn't numeric in sort at foo.pl line 6, <DATA> line 5.
Argument "32    0       4\n" isn't numeric in sort at foo.pl line 6, <DATA> line 5.
Argument "11    2       3\n" isn't numeric in sort at foo.pl line 6, <DATA> line 5.
Argument "1     3       3\n" isn't numeric in sort at foo.pl line 6, <DATA> line 5.
0       1       2
1       3       3
11      2       3
21      13      14
32      0       4
```

But as you can see, it has sorted correctly. I would not advice this solution, but it is a nice demonstration in this context, I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the complete explanations. I tried the above but just replaced `<DATA>` with `@data` which is a list containing my lines. I get the following error though: `Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at ./mergedata line 53, <> line 20.`

Comment: @ManiBastaniParizi That's because you have an undefined value in your array. If you want to inspect your data, try `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@data;`

Comment: @ManiBastaniParizi Oh right, you said you can have negative values... then you need a different regex, I will edit to fix that.

Comment: I imagine this is because the numbers are real numbers. Some of them might start with `-` and can contain the floating point. So I guess I should change the regular expression. Am I right?

Comment: @ManiBastaniParizi Yes.. it might be simplest to just use `\S+` for the capture, assuming all non-whitespace there are valid numerical characters.

Comment: @FMc `/^(\S+)/` is similar to `(split)[0]`, but less dangerous, since split will also return false values in the case of missing data in the first column.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the sort function :

```
@sorted_data = sort(@data);
```

Comment: This will not do what was asked since it sorts lexically and not  numerically as requested.

Comment: Thanks but this will sort them in the lexicographical order, for example -1 will appear before -2. I want them to be sorted in numerical order.

Comment: -1. Did you try it? This will place `10` before `2`.